# How to read logs in text file when using java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, json, web-services, logging

I want to read `String` data from MyLogFile.log which I write in D:/MyLogFile.log.

I want to read JSON data(web service) from file. Can any one help it out?

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Log {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        FileHandler fh;
        try {
            // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
            fh = new FileHandler("D:/MyLogFile.log");
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);
            // the following statement is used to log any messages
            logger.info("My first log");
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("Hi How r u?");
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up packages: `java.util.logging` package is used for logging, that is: **writing log files**. Reading files is usually done with the help of `java.io` (IO means input/output, so you can use it for writing plain files, too). It doesn't matter if the file you are reading is a log file or something else, as long as it is readable.

so you simply could start with that:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/MyLogFile.log"));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // do something
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```